# Add text on image like status creation in whatsApp and facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to achieve this kind of style in `UITextView` same like WhatsApp, Facebook and Instagram status. Where we can add a background color to text only parts and it will expand if we continue writing it.

Here is the image for more details. :

[image: Here is the image for more details.]

Comment: Please rework your question. The Headline should be clear. Post the image in the text.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question.

Comment: My suggestion is that you have to make function that will create label base on text and add that on Your image

Comment: You can get some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169082/uitextview-highlight-text-with-nsbackgroundcolor-exclude-line-breaks)

Answer (score -1):

Write following code in UITextViewDelegate method. On each word the textview delegate get call and you can apply the background color for textview text.

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textField.text)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.clear, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: textField.text.length))
textField.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Thanks Bhushan for the response but i don't wants the image, I wants textview which having the feature to apply background color to text, something like the image that i have attached in my quetion.